# rpy2: converting DataFrames -> data.frames

Tags: python, r, dataframe, datetime, rpy2

I'm trying to pass a `pandas` `DataFrame` object to an R function and have it become a `data.frame` in R-land.  According to docs like https://rpy2.github.io/doc/latest/html/pandas.html, this should be possible using its implicit conversion stuff.

However, I'm having a lot of trouble getting it to work well.  For example, datetime data doesn't seem to be supported:

```
import pandas as pd
import rpy2.robjects as ro
from rpy2.robjects import pandas2ri
from rpy2.robjects.conversion import localconverter

ro.r("my_r_function <- function(now, data) { data[data$datetime >= now, ] }")

now = pd.to_datetime('2022-02-22 02:22:22Z')
data = pd.DataFrame({'datetime': now + pd.to_timedelta([-1, 0, 1], 'hours'),
                     'location': 'Toledo',
                     'variable': 'smell',
                     'value': 'rosy'})

with localconverter(ro.default_converter + pandas2ri.converter):
    result = ro.r['my_r_function'](now, data)
```

That raises the exception `NotImplementedError: Conversion 'py2rpy' not defined for objects of type '<class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp'>'` for the `now` argument and the `datetime` column.  If I change the `now` argument to `now.to_pydatetime()`, I get `NotImplementedError: Conversion 'py2rpy' not defined for objects of type '<class 'datetime.datetime'>'`.

There are a lot of examples on SO and elsewhere referencing `pandas2ri.activate()`, but that seems to now be deprecated and scheduled for removal.

Will I need to [figure out how to] write custom converters for `pd.Timestamp` and `datetime` and `pd.Timedelta` and all that stuff?  Or are there converters around that I just haven't found or figured out how to use?

Comment: what do you mean by not supported? `datetime` is a date. eg `2022-07-25 15:48:32`. How do you want this to be compared to a number like 6? What does that even mean? Probably you need `timedelta`(python)  type and note datetime type.

Comment: Ack that was a typo, fixing now - the `6` is supposed to be `now` and illustrates the problem.  By "not supported" I mean their conversions don't seem to be supported by `rpy2`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to write your own converter as `pandas2ri` module does not include  a converter for `Timestamp`. Try this:

```py
import pandas as pd
import rpy2.robjects as ro
from rpy2.robjects import pandas2ri, DateVector
from rpy2.robjects.conversion import localconverter

from rpy2 import situation

ro.r("my_r_function <- function(now, data) { data[data$datetime >= now, ] }")

now = pd.to_datetime('2022-02-22 02:22:22Z')
data = pd.DataFrame({'datetime': now + pd.to_timedelta([-1, 0, 1], 'hours'),
                     'location': 'Toledo',
                     'variable': 'smell',
                     'value': 'rosy'})

print(data)

# create your own converter
cv = ro.default_converter + pandas2ri.converter

# add a conversion function for Pandas Timestamp to R DateVector
@cv.py2rpy.register(pd.Timestamp)
def Timestamp2DateVector(val):
    return DateVector([val])

with localconverter(cv):
    result = ro.r['my_r_function'](now, data)
```

Creating and registering your custom conversion function is not too hard although I couldn't figure it out from documentation and had to deepdive. The key in this particular case is that R variables are all arrays by construct (I think, I actually have never used R on its own) so you need to put your `Timestamp` variable in a sequence as done above.

Comment: Thanks @kesh - I wonder if I can contribute some of this functionality to `pandas2ri`, it would be nice to not have to maintain this in our personal code.

Comment: The other type I'm having trouble with is `pd.Timedelta`, this technique doesn't seem to work with it (maybe because of `numpy` delegation?).  Would it be appropriate to add that to the original question, or ask a new one?

Comment: Not `numpy` but the source python object must have `.toordinal()` method. Is there an R class that is comparable to `Timedelta` or can it be just a float value? (the latter is what `DateVector` is from what I can tell.)

Comment: As for contribution, I'd post an issue first to see if the owner is interested in having it

Comment: The most common timedelta classes in R are `difftime` (built-in) and `period`, `duration`, and `interval`(all from the `lubridate` package).

Comment: I do think I'll open an issue in `rpy2`'s tracker, because even the `pd.Timestamp` conversion doesn't seem to be working consistently (e.g., different results if it's not a column in a `DataFrame`).

Comment: It's possible to create a converter to `difftime` but is it necessary for what you want to do?   For example, I use `rpy2` purely to run stat tests so the actual R datatype is less of importance. If you are on a same boat, you can just convert it to a float.

Comment: so actually I think this `Timestamp` conversion doesn't work - it seems to come through as the integer `738208`, not the `POSIXt` I'm hoping for.  I opened an issue at https://github.com/rpy2/rpy2/issues/912 .

Comment: I see so you want to convert to a S3 class object. I'm a bit busy for the next few days, but I can get back with you if issue is not solved by then